# What does "take a high line" means?

Tags: meaning, literature, archaicisms

Quote:"The greatest and perhaps the wealthiest. I am aware, Mr. Holmes, that you take a very high line in professional matters, and that you are prepared to work for the work's sake. I may tell you, however, that his Grace has already intimated that a cheque for five thousand pounds will be handed over to the person who can tell him where his son is, and another thousand to him who can name the man, or men, who have taken him."

Answer (score 2):

You can find it from a dictionary but there are a lot of possible meanings for the words, so it may be hard to work which specific meanings apply.

**High** means "exalted or elevated in character : NOBLE" (sense 7 in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/high))

**Line** means "a course of conduct, action, or thought" (sense 4a in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/line))

So together "you take a very high line" means "you conduct yourself in a way that is very elevated or noble", which here means "you are not motivated by money but by nobler motives". Being driven by a desire for money was considered vulgar in Conan Doyle's time, and is often viewed the same today.

Comment: "Vulgar": common, ordinary, general, usual. plebian. In Conan Doyle's time, indicating that you were inferior by reason of birth, demonstrated by lack of inherited wealth and interest in acquiring same.